# Missing some css classes in VueJS3+Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

We have old VueJS+Vuetify application which we are converting to VueJS3. We have some classes defined in the template which is not available in the new version.

There are classes like `xs12` (which suppose to cover full screen), `text-xs-left` (which suppose to set the left align text), `offset-xs2` (which suppose to set the offset). There are many like this which is available in VueJS2+Vuetify which are missing in new version.

How to add those classes in the new VueJS3+Vuetify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xs` classes were removed in favor of the breakpoint-free version, i.e. `text-left` instead of `text-xs-left`. Specifications for a size apply to all larger sizes, and since `xs` is the smallest size, specifications on that level apply to all other sizes, same as the breakpoint-free version.

For the text class, this is mentioned in the [upgrade guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/#styles-and-utility-classes):

> `.text-xs-{alignment}` has been renamed to `.text-{alignment}` to reflect the fact that it applies to all breakpoints.

(I think the offset and column classes are considered internal, there is no documentation on them.)

So you either have to add those classes yourself or update the classes:

- `xs12`: use `v-col-12` (this one was also renamed)
- `text-xs-left`: use `text-left`
- `offset-xs2`: use `offset-2` (larger sizes now have a dash between breakpoint and width, i.e. `offset-lg-2`)

Comment: is there anywhere mentioned about this mapping like `xs12` is `v-col-12` ?

Comment: I think column and offset classes are considered internal, as you typically set them through props. The change to the text classes is mentioned in the upgrade guide, I have added a link to the answer.

Comment: thanks Moritz, its really help a lot.